# Quantifier + proper name

Tags: word-usage, quantifiers

How should I use **QUANTIFIERS** with **PROPER NOUNS**? What's the proper form?

e.G:

> **Each of** Johnson's cars has one different color.

> **Some of** Carl's cattle heads have no pedigree.

> **All of** Ryder's companies have a regional manager.

Please **do not consider this question as proofreading.** I would like to know just which is the grammatically correct form when referring to a proper noun.

Thank you!

Comment: There's two mistakes that I think are unrelated to your question, which will cause confusion. I recommend changing "one different color" to "**a** different color", and "cattle heads" to "**head of cattle**" (yes, singular "head") or just "**cattle**" without "head".

Comment: Beyond that, you've used all the quantifiers correctly, but none of those are proper nouns. "Johnson" is a proper noun, but "Johnson's cars" isn't. The head noun is "cars". "Johnson's" modifies "cars".

Comment: Thank you for your observations, @gotube!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors in the use of quantifiers. The proper nouns are used as possessive and function as determiners.

So there is no error in "Each of Johnson's cars...."  The grammatical structure is equivalent to "Each of the cars..."

There are, as noted in comments, errors in the other parts of the sentence  <sub>but as I am not considering this as proofreading, I'll let those pass.</sub>

Comment: *Do not feed the bears!* (If I could, I'd give you *another* upvote just for that final disclaimer! :)

Comment: Thank you again, James.

So "Each of the cars of Lucian" is equivalent to "Each of Lucian's cars..." ?

Comment: yes,  those two are equivalent, but you would only normally say "Each of Lucian's cars."